# Access VBA Subscript out of range loading DAO.Recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I am seeing inconsistent results and getting a subscript out of range error when I try to load and use a recordset from an Access query. I am loading from this query:
[record source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeaN9.png)

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function StoreStockoutEmail()
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
   Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
   Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
   Dim dtStr As String
   Dim rstData    As DAO.Recordset
   Dim v  As Variant
   Dim i, j, k, x, y As Integer
   Dim mymsg As String

   mymsg = ""

    Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Store_Stockouts")
    v = rstData.GetRows(rstData.RecordCount)
    If Not rstData.EOF And Not rstData.BOF Then
    rstData.MoveLast
    i = rstData.RecordCount
    rstData.MoveFirst


    MsgBox (v(0, 2))
   ...
```

The MsgBox is where I get Runtime error 9 "Subscript out of range", but my data source has a data point at 0,2 (and 2,0). (I added the EOF and BOF movement based on another answer, but it didn't help.) I feel that this could be a bug, because this has worked for some recordsets and not for others. MS Access for Micosoft 365 32-bit. References added for MS DAO 3.6 Object Library. Thanks!

Comment: Where is `CurrentDb` coming from? It's not defined in this code, I'm wondering if it's being recycled properly.

Comment: Try `Debug.Print rstData.RecordCount` before running the GetRows  - what's the output?

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Williams hinted, `rstData.RecordCount` may not be correct until you did the `.MoveLast / .MoveFirst` dance. (See Note 2)

The check for `rstData.EOF` should directly follow `.OpenRecordset`. Checking for `.BOF` here is unnecessary (cargo cult).

So the code should be:

```
Set rstData = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Store_Stockouts")
If Not rstData.EOF Then
    rstData.MoveLast
    i = rstData.RecordCount
    rstData.MoveFirst

    v = rstData.GetRows(i)
```

---

Side note:

```
   Dim i, j, k, x, y As Integer
```

This declares everything as Variant, only `y` will be Integer.

---

Note 2:

*I feel that this could be a bug, because this has worked for some recordsets and not for others.*

This is by design. Allen Browne explains it in 4. here: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html

> For recordsets based on queries, SQL statements, and attached tables, the RecordCount property returns the number of records accessed so far. When you first OpenRecordset(), Access grabs the first record, and keeps processing your code while the others load.
>   So, if you test RecordCount immediately after you OpenRecordset, you typically get 0 (if there are no records), or 1 (if there are any, regardless of how many will load.)
>   This does not apply to recordsets of type dbOpenTable type (the default for local tables.)
>
> **Solution:**
>
> If you need to know the RecordCount, use the MoveLast method first. This forces Access to wait while all records load, so the RecordCount reflects the entire recordset.